# Rally Rest API: Querying data from nested projects

Tags: rally

I am trying to query data from a project in Rally to build automated report dashboard for my project. The Rally workspace/project tree structure looks like as below:

```
Workspace
    Parent project
        Project1
        Project2
        Proejct3
           Team1
           Team2
           Team3
```

I am trying to query defects/Test cases that are available under all projects(Team1, Team2 & Team3) only

Please help

Comment: Can you reformat your post so we can tell what structure you were trying to convey?  It is hard to answer with it formatted flat.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume your projects have Object IDs as follows

```
Proejct3 (111)
   Team1 (222)
   Team2 (333)
   Team3 (444)
```

If you want to query all items from Project 3 and its children you can simply include the queryString `project=/project/111&projectScopeDown=true`

If you want to include only Team1, Team2, and Team3 you cannot use the project scoping query string and should instead use the `query` param

example

```
query=((Project = /project/222) OR ((Project = /project/333) OR (Project = /project/444)))
```